# Pedestal Fan stopped working

Tags: fans

Thanks in advance but my 2 year old LASKO Pedestal Fan (1880C) suddenly stopped working. The power goes to the control panel so it is not the cord. There is no hum, so it may not be the capacitor. I spun it with power on, and it doesn't spin - so it may not be the capacitor. I cleaned it, no effect.

Cord is ok, cleaning doesn't help and there is no hum. What could be the issue? Any help is appreciated. I don't like throwing things and increasing landfill. I want to repair.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have narrowed it down to the motor. Next, You could see if you can take it apart and replace the brushes and inspect the internals.

Comment: You say there is power at the control panel, but what about *from the control panel to the motor*, did you test for power at the motor? I ask because a control panel button/switch would be a likely candidate for failure...

Comment: >>but what about from the control panel to the motor, did you test for power at the motor? I ask because a control panel button/switch would be a likely candidate for failure..



How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed mine very similar several times , these are very low wattage motors so when the bearings dry out they seize. Use some oil 30 weight or whatever you have, even liquid cooking oil can work olive or crisco but may not last as long as motor oil.

Tilt the motor back and put a couple of drops on the shaft and rotate by hand as the oil is absorbed add a few more drops continue rotating. If you feel it freeing up keep going until 10 to 20 drops are in there there is a fiber pocket that can hold close yo a teaspoon worth of oil if it’s not running out it’s not over full.
If some oil runs into the motor don’t sweat it pi’s has insulation qualities but connects dust.
The first few times I did our fan I only had to do the front that is the main load on the motor. The last time I had to do the rear and like yours the oscillating mechanics were in the way I finally took it apart and filled the rear bearing. I think this fan is close to 20 years old and every 2-3 years I have to oil the front bearing, once it frees up I turn it on and let it spin , then off and a few more drops, turn on, I just try to get the oil lite bearings fully saturated, mine is almost done as the shaft was sloppy in the bearing last tile but it is still working for now.

You have done the hard Part now add oil and you will probably have it working in 10 minutes or less.

Comment: I would not recommend vegetable oils, they can spoil over time creating bad smells and aren't necessarily very good lubricants.

Comment: Did you read I said they don’t last as long In a pinch they will work even wd40 can get it working . Natural oils can go bad but I have used olive oil and it worked great I had a customer that I fixed his bathroom fan and showed him how to do it that’s what was available for more than 10 years every time he saw me he told me that he had to oil it again when he passed his wife sent me a gallon of imported olive oil from Italy and a few other things he put in his will and the fan was still working when she sold the house. She passed a few weeks ago but for someone that may have that it can work.

Comment: Hi Ed,
Thanks for the detailed answer but it didn't work.

Comment: If the motor shaft spins and you have power after the H,M,L switches it is probably the motor windings, , if you have a meter with the fan unplugged measure the resistance of the windings it should be a low value if open the motor windings are open and usually not repairable.

Comment: Is it feasible to buy a replacement fan motor and replace it?

Comment: I don’t think so I do replace motors in hand held grinders but these parts are easy to locate online, the armature for a grinder or the last one I ordered was close to 75$ , most folks just toss the fan, I get a few repairs unless plastic bushings holding things in place then when the bearings overheat they are toast.